# probability winning and losing question

Tags: probability

How to find the probability that someone wins the first seven times in a row  and loses the last three in a row if theres $10$ rounds.Probability of winning is $0.8$ .

I tried to us the formula $({10 \choose 7}) (0.8)^7$ $(1-0.8)^3$ and I got $0.201$

Comment: That's the wrong formula.  The combinations factor is there so that you count all the different possible orders things could happen.  You don't want different ways, you want one very specific way, 7 wins then 3 losses.

Comment: Oh ok ,so would I instead use the binomial distribution formula ?

Comment: Same formula, just omit the coefficient, is the result.  You want the first to be a win, AND the second to be a win, AND,...AND the eighth to be a lose, AND...When you want the probability of this AND that, and they are independent, then you multiply the probabilities.  So you get 0.8*0.8*...*0.8*0.2*0.2*0.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula is actually $0.8^7 * (1 - 0.8)^3 = 0.8^7 * 0.2^3 \approx \boxed{0.0016}$.

Since the probability of winning is $0.8$ and there are $7$ wins and each is independent, you have $0.8^7$. You also have to multiply by $(1 - 0.8)^3$ because you need to count the losses too. That's how to get the formula.

Hope this answer helped!

Comment: It did thank you and yes I was meant to say $(10choose7)$

Comment: @user912758 no problem :) have a great day